# Kafka connection issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache-kafka

I have installed Kafka on docker swarm, But I am continuously facing below issue.

Can anyone shed some light on what issue is ? and what I am missing here ?

```html
fastlane_accounts_service_subscriber_kafka.1.yoh6ytisqt3x@ip-10-0-1-109.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal    | bundler: failed to load command: bin/subscriber_kafka (bin/subscriber_kafka)
fastlane_accounts_service_subscriber_kafka.1.z5uwnusziv2g@ip-10-0-1-109.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal    | I, [2018-10-21T07:37:41.204851 #1]  INFO -- : Leaving group `accounts_service.account`
fastlane_accounts_service_subscriber_kafka.1.z5uwnusziv2g@ip-10-0-1-109.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal    | D, [2018-10-21T07:37:41.204879 #1] DEBUG -- : Getting group coordinator for `accounts_service.account`
fastlane_accounts_service_subscriber_kafka.1.yoh6ytisqt3x@ip-10-0-1-109.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal    |   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/ruby-kafka-0.7.2/lib/kafka/cluster.rb:121:in `get_group_coordinator'
fastlane_accounts_service_subscriber_kafka.1.z5uwnusziv2g@ip-10-0-1-109.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal    | D, [2018-10-21T07:37:41.204927 #1] DEBUG -- : Opening connection to ip-10-0-1-109.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal:9094 with client id ruby-kafka...
fastlane_accounts_service_subscriber_kafka.1.z5uwnusziv2g@ip-10-0-1-109.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal    | E, [2018-10-21T07:37:41.204555 #1] ERROR -- : Failed to connect to ip-10-0-1-109.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal:9094: getaddrinfo: Try again
fastlane_accounts_service_subscriber_kafka.1.yoh6ytisqt3x@ip-10-0-1-109.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal    |   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/ruby-kafka-0.7.2/lib/kafka/consumer_group.rb:190:in `coordinator'
fastlane_accounts_service_subscriber_kafka.1.z5uwnusziv2g@ip-10-0-1-109.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal    | D, [2018-10-21T07:37:41.206519 #1] DEBUG -- : Closing socket to ip-10-0-1-109.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal:9094
fastlane_accounts_service_subscriber_kafka.1.z5uwnusziv2g@ip-10-0-1-109.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal    | E, [2018-10-21T07:37:41.206599 #1] ERROR -- : Failed to get coordinator info from ip-10-0-1-109.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal:9094 (node_id=109): getaddrinfo: Try again
fastlane_accounts_service_subscriber_kafka.1.yoh6ytisqt3x@ip-10-0-1-109.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal    |   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/ruby-kafka-0.7.2/lib/kafka/consumer_group.rb:131:in `block in join_group'
fastlane_accounts_service_subscriber_kafka.1.z5uwnusziv2g@ip-10-0-1-109.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal    | I, [2018-10-21T07:37:41.206633 #1]  INFO -- : Leaving group `accounts_service.customer`
fastlane_accounts_service_subscriber_kafka.1.z5uwnusziv2g@ip-10-0-1-109.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal    | D, [2018-10-21T07:37:41.206660 #1] DEBUG -- : Getting group coordinator for `accounts_service.customer`
fastlane_accounts_service_subscriber_kafka.1.yoh6ytisqt3x@ip-10-0-1-109.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal    |   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:170:in `instrument'
fastlane_accounts_service_subscriber_kafka.1.z5uwnusziv2g@ip-10-0-1-109.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal    | D, [2018-10-21T07:37:41.206717 #1] DEBUG -- : Opening connection to ip-10-0-1-109.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal:9094 with client id ruby-kafka...
fastlane_accounts_service_subscriber_kafka.1.z5uwnusziv2g@ip-10-0-1-109.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal    | D, [2018-10-21T07:37:41.222250 #1] DEBUG -- : Handling fetcher command: stop
fastlane_accounts_service_subscriber_kafka.1.yoh6ytisqt3x@ip-10-0-1-109.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal    |   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/ruby-kafka-0.7.2/lib/kafka/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
fastlane_accounts_service_subscriber_kafka.1.z5uwnusziv2g@ip-10-0-1-109.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal    | D, [2018-10-21T07:37:41.222428 #1] DEBUG -- : Handling fetcher command: stop
fastlane_accounts_service_subscriber_kafka.1.yoh6ytisqt3x@ip-10-0-1-109.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal    |   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/ruby-kafka-0.7.2/lib/kafka/instrumenter.rb:35:in `instrument'
fastlane_accounts_service_subscriber_kafka.1.yoh6ytisqt3x@ip-10-0-1-109.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal    |   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/ruby-kafka-0.7.2/lib/kafka/consumer_group.rb:130:in `join_group'
fastlane_accounts_service_subscriber_kafka.1.z5uwnusziv2g@ip-10-0-1-109.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal    | D, [2018-10-21T07:37:41.222955 #1] DEBUG -- : Handling fetcher command: stop
fastlane_accounts_service_subscriber_kafka.1.z5uwnusziv2g@ip-10-0-1-109.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal    | E, [2018-10-21T07:37:46.208336 #1] ERROR -- : Failed to connect to ip-10-0-1-109.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal:9094: getaddrinfo: Try again
fastlane_accounts_service_subscriber_kafka.1.yoh6ytisqt3x@ip-10-0-1-109.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal    |   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/ruby-kafka-0.7.2/lib/kafka/consumer_group.rb:47:in `join'
fastlane_accounts_service_subscriber_kafka.1.z5uwnusziv2g@ip-10-0-1-109.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal    | D, [2018-10-21T07:37:46.208412 #1] DEBUG -- : Closing socket to ip-10-0-1-109.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal:9094
fastlane_accounts_service_subscriber_kafka.1.z5uwnusziv2g@ip-10-0-1-109.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal    | E, [2018-10-21T07:37:46.208545 #1] ERROR -- : Failed to get coordinator info from ip-10-0-1-109.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal:9094 (node_id=109): getaddrinfo: Try again
fastlane_accounts_service_subscriber_kafka.1.yoh6ytisqt3x@ip-10-0-1-109.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal    |   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/ruby-kafka-0.7.2/lib/kafka/consumer.rb:443:in `join_group'
fastlane_accounts_service_subscriber_kafka.1.z5uwnusziv2g@ip-10-0-1-109.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal    | E, [2018-10-21T07:37:46.208265 #1] ERROR -- : Failed to connect to ip-10-0-1-109.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal:9094: getaddrinfo: Try again
fastlane_accounts_service_subscriber_kafka.1.yoh6ytisqt3x@ip-10-0-1-109.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal    |   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/ruby-kafka-0.7.2/lib/kafka/consumer.rb:506:in `fetch_batches'
fastlane_accounts_service_subscriber_kafka.1.z5uwnusziv2g@ip-10-0-1-109.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal    | D, [2018-10-21T07:37:46.208815 #1] DEBUG -- : Closing socket to ip-10-0-1-109.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal:9094
fastlane_accounts_service_subscriber_kafka.1.z5uwnusziv2g@ip-10-0-1-109.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal    | E, [2018-10-21T07:37:46.208867 #1] ERROR -- : Failed to get coordinator info from ip-10-0-1-109.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal:9094 (node_id=109): getaddrinfo: Try again
fastlane_accounts_service_subscriber_kafka.1.yoh6ytisqt3x@ip-10-0-1-109.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal    |   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/ruby-kafka-0.7.2/lib/kafka/consumer.rb:206:in `block in each_message'
fastlane_accounts_service_subscriber_kafka.1.yoh6ytisqt3x@ip-10-0-1-109.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal    |   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/ruby-kafka-0.7.2/lib/kafka/consumer.rb:394:in `block in consumer_loop'
fastlane_accounts_service_subscriber_kafka.1.z5uwnusziv2g@ip-10-0-1-109.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal    | E, [2018-10-21T07:37:46.209073 #1] ERROR -- : Failed to connect to ip-10-0-1-109.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal:9094: getaddrinfo: Try again
fastlane_accounts_service_subscriber_kafka.1.z5uwnusziv2g@ip-10-0-1-109.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal    | D, [2018-10-21T07:37:46.209110 #1] DEBUG -- : Closing socket to ip-10-0-1-109.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal:9094
fastlane_accounts_service_subscriber_kafka.1.yoh6ytisqt3x@ip-10-0-1-109.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal    |   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:170:in `instrument'
fastlane_accounts_service_subscriber_kafka.1.yoh6ytisqt3x@ip-10-0-1-109.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal    |   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/ruby-kafka-0.7.2/lib/kafka/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
fastlane_accounts_service_subscriber_kafka.1.z5uwnusziv2g@ip-10-0-1-109.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal    | E, [2018-10-21T07:37:46.209170 #1] ERROR -- : Failed to get coordinator info from ip-10-0-1-109.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal:9094 (node_id=109): getaddrinfo: Try again
fastlane_accounts_service_subscriber_kafka.1.yoh6ytisqt3x@ip-10-0-1-109.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal    |   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/ruby-kafka-0.7.2/lib/kafka/instrumenter.rb:35:in `instrument'
fastlane_accounts_service_subscriber_kafka.1.z5uwnusziv2g@ip-10-0-1-109.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal    | bundler: failed to load command: bin/subscriber_kafka (bin/subscriber_kafka)
fastlane_accounts_service_subscriber_kafka.1.yoh6ytisqt3x@ip-10-0-1-109.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal    |   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/ruby-kafka-0.7.2/lib/kafka/consumer.rb:393:in `consumer_loop'
fastlane_accounts_service_subscriber_kafka.1.yoh6ytisqt3x@ip-10-0-1-109.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal    |   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/ruby-kafka-0.7.2/lib/kafka/consumer.rb:205:in `each_message'
fastlane_accounts_service_subscriber_kafka.1.yoh6ytisqt3x@ip-10-0-1-109.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal    |   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/kafka_tools-0.2.0/lib/kafka_tools/consumer.rb:65:in `listen_messages'
fastlane_accounts_service_subscriber_kafka.1.yoh6ytisqt3x@ip-10-0-1-109.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal    |   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/kafka_tools-0.2.0/lib/kafka_tools/consumer.rb:20:in `run'
fastlane_accounts_service_subscriber_kafka.1.yoh6ytisqt3x@ip-10-0-1-109.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal    |   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/kafka_tools-0.2.0/lib/kafka_tools.rb:26:in `block (2 levels) in consume'
```

My Docker Swarm config

```html
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper:latest
    networks:
      - fastlane
    deploy:
      mode: global

  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka:latest
    ports:
      - target: 9094
        published: 9094
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
    environment:
      HOSTNAME_COMMAND: ${KAFKA_HOSTNAME_COMMAND}
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INSIDE:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INSIDE://:9092,OUTSIDE://_{HOSTNAME_COMMAND}:9094
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INSIDE://:9092,OUTSIDE://:9094
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INSIDE
      BROKER_ID_COMMAND: ${BROKER_ID_COMMAND}
    networks:
      - fastlane
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper

  kafka_manager:
    image: deric/kafka-manager:1.3.3.18
    networks:
      - fastlane
    environment:
      ZK_HOSTS: zookeeper:2181
      APPLICATION_SECRET: letmein
    deploy:
      labels:
        - traefik.backend.loadbalancer.swarm=true
        - traefik.backend=kafka-manager
        - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:kafka-manager.${DOMAIN}
        - traefik.port=9000
        - traefik.docker.network=fastlane
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
```

```
KAFKA_HOSTNAME_COMMAND = curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-hostname
BROKER_ID_COMMAND="curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4 | awk -F '.' '{print \$4}'"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you look at the README? It specifically mentions what needs to be done to run in AWS

> If `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME` is specified, it takes precedence over `HOSTNAME_COMMAND`
>
> For AWS deployment, you can use the Metadata service to get the container host's IP:
>
> `HOSTNAME_COMMAND=wget -t3 -T2 -qO-  http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4`
>
> Reference: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html

So, first, try what the docs say exactly before something else, and remove the spaces around an equal sign for `KAFKA_HOSTNAME_COMMAND =`

If you running the Ruby code locally, not in the AWS network, you need to get the above commands to return external addresses after you open the Kafka ports from the VPC settings in AWS console.

I would like to mention that it would be easier to connect to the Kafka instances if your Ruby application(a) also are part of the Compose file. For example, using an overlay network or Træfik, you could access `kafka:9094` service directly.

Comment: One more thing, if your Kafka or Zookeeper containers restart, you'll lose all the data

Comment: My Ruby application which connects with Kafka container also the part of same compose file (v3).

Comment: I changed the value of KAFKA_HOSTNAME_COMMAND to below and it works as expected.
    KAFKA_HOSTNAME_COMMAND=wget -t3 -T2 -qO-  http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4

Comment: Cool. It might make sense to use Traefik to load balance your Kafka brokers as well, then you could use that in your Ruby app